# While loop count off by + one

Tags: c#, while-loop, count

When inputting items in my code my count is off by +1 because it is counting my -1 command in the price as an item. How do I decrease the item count by 1?

```
double price = 0;
double input = 0;
const double _TAX = .065;
double items;
double tax;
double total;
double counter = 1;

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Item #{0}   Enter Price: $", ++counter);
    input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    if (input == - 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    price += input;
}

items = counter - 1; //no matter what I do I cant get the correct count
Console.WriteLine("\n   Items:   {0}", items);
```

Comment: Use `counter++` instead of  `++counter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
    double price = 0;
    double input = 0;
    const double _TAX = .065;
    double tax;
    double total;
    int count = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Item #{0}   Enter Price: $", count);
        input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (input == - 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        count++
        price += input;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n   Items:   {0}", count);
```